mirrored object's movement is wrong
this question was propably asked many times but i don't know how to properly phrase it but basically  i have these two hands 
let's call them hand 1 and 2 for simplicity left to right
when i move hand 2 hand 1 does move accordingly but is there way to mirror it on z axis?

as you can see hand 2 is perfectly fine but hand 1 is kinda goofy looking


It looks as if  the pivot point of the mirror is not in the centre as the object's origin (orange dot) has moved off-centre on the second image. Add a screenshot of the whole screen via Blender's Window > Save Screenshot to your question and share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it so that we can see exactly what's going on.

Set the 'Mirror Object' to the pants or torso in the modifier. Or you can move the hands in edit mode. Otherwise, when you move the hand, you are moving its origin, which is what the mirror modifier uses as the default point to mirror


Not sure if this is what you mean but on the Mirror mod, you can set another object to be the source of the mirror on 'Mirror Object'. Use the dropper to click any of the parts that won't move from the middle, like the head, or create an empty and use that instead.

Are they at a different Z coordinate to begin with?
If so, I'd set them first of all to the same height.
To do so, go to object mode and select the hand that is in the right position and click N. You should see a tool bar with the object's coordinate that looks like this:

Copy the Z location of that object.
Then go the second hand click N and paste the previous Z coordinate to the Z coordinate of this object.
This way they would be set to the same height to begin with and when you move them together the Z axis would be mirrored.

i used mirror modifier so they are on the same hight i just wonder if there is way to make it mirror in such way so that if i bring one closer to torso other also goes closer to torso instead farther, like if one would do opposite direction but only in one axis

they are the same location cuz one is just mirrored version of the other and not separate object, but i propably just messed my explenantion in last reply so i made drawning so maybe you can understand what im trying to say
